# Rails authentication \ Simple Ruby question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This might seem really simple, but I'm a bit confused

Here's some simple authentication code:

```
def self.authenticate(username="", password="")
    user = AdminUser.find_by_username(username)

    if user && user.password_match?(password)
        return user
    else
        return false
    end
end

def password_match? (password)
    hashed_password == AdminUser.hash_with_salt(password, salt)
end
```

My question is, in def password_match?, how does it have access to what's inside the user object? Because user calls it? So if it said "hashed_pwd" instead of "hashed_password" it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the surrounding class that this belongs to.  Presumably it belongs in a User class:

```
class User
  def self.authenticate(username="", password="")
    user = AdminUser.find_by_username(username)

    if user && user.password_match?(password)
        return user
    else
        return false
    end
  end

  def password_match? (password)
    hashed_password == AdminUser.hash_with_salt(password, salt)
  end
end
```

And so yes, it is a method on that class.

```
user = User.authenticate("joe","12345")

user.password_match?("12345")
```

Notice how one is called one the class, and one is called on the object  instantiated from that class.

As Paul mentioned, it is a shortcut for `self.hashed_password` ... But you can get into trouble using that shortcut, especially when assigning to it -
  `hashed_password = "..."` in this case, ruby may not know whether it is a method or a variable, and it may assign the value to a local variable instead of calling the `hashed_password=()` method as you may expect.  Always use `self.hashed_password=()` when assigning to an attribute. :)

Comment: "*May* assign the value to a local variable"? `something = "..."` will *always* create a local variable. If there's no `.` in the LHS, you're creating a local variable. If there is a `.`, you're calling a setter method.

Comment: well, weird things happen if you had previously used self.something= ... I suspect that rails uses method_missing at first,but when it is called makes a real method on it.  from that point on it uses the accessor.

Answer (score 1):

yes you are basically right, because that is really just shorthand for

```
self.hashed_password == hashed_password == Admin....
```

so anything else wouldn't work